# `Synchronized` not working in XCTest

Tags: objective-c, xcode, xctest

I have an app that contains a cocoapod that contains the engine behind the app. In this cocoapod, I have a shared instance of the basic class.

```
+ (Restaurant *)current {
    @synchronized(self) {
        if (current == nil) {
            current = [[Restaurant alloc] initWithId:0];
        }
    }
    return current;
}
```

Now, I'm running some unittests on some other code in my app. That looks like this:

```
- (void)testPOSTCodeGeneration {
    [[Restaurant current] setMainTable:4];

    NSLog(@"Main table in test: %d", [[Restaurant current] mainTable]);

    Generator *generator = [[Generator alloc] init];

    XCTAssertEqualObjects([[Restaurant current] mainTable], generator.table);
}
```

And in `Generator.m`, I do something along the lines of this:

```
- (void)init {
    ...
    self.table = [[Restaurant current] mainTable];
    ...
}
```

The strange thing is, that this test fails. `mainTable` has a default of 0 unless a different number is set. So even though I set it to be 4 (and `Main table in test:` logs a 4), it returns 0. Is `@synchronized` incompatible with Xcode unittests? Or does anyone know what else is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple recommends to use dispatch_once instead of synchronized so can you try this code :

```
+ (Restaurant *)current {
    static Restaurant *current=nil:
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken = 0;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
       current = [[Restaurant alloc] initWithId:0];
    }
    return current;
}
```

Link to apple documentation: https://developer.apple.com/reference/dispatch/1447169-dispatch_once

Answer (score 0):

`mainTable` is not an object, so don't call `XCTAssertEqualObjects`. Instead use `XCTAssertEquals`.